# Octave access elements of matrix by lines

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I made a matrix like this :

```
A = randi([-10, 10], 3, 3);
```

Which can have this result :

```
-1    1   -2
2    2    8
5    3   10
```

How can I transform it in a way that A(1) = -1, A(2) = 1 and A(3) = -2
(Accessing first line with terms 1,2,3)

Currently, A(1) = -1, A(2) = 2 and A(3) = 5 (columns)

Note : Not only the first line, but I want to access all elements sorted by lines

Thank you !

Comment: Use `A.'(1)` , `A.'(2)`, `A.'(3)`. See [`transpose`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/Arithmetic-Ops.html#XREFtranspose)

Comment: Thanks, did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Octave and MATLAB, data is stored in column-major order which means for your matrix, indices and elements are like this:

[image: A matrix]

You need to take the [transpose](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Arithmetic-Ops.html#XREFtranspose) of the original matrix to access them the way you stated. In Octave, you can directly access them using `A.'(1)` , `A.'(2)`, `A.'(3)` etc. In MATLAB, you cannot access them like Octave. So save them in a new matrix or replace the contents of the previous matrix. i.e. `A = A.'` and then you can use `A(1)`, `A(2)`, `A(3)` etc to access the desired elements.

`A.'` or `transpose(A)` for the given `A` actually gives:

[image: transpose(A)]

So now as per the column major order, first, second and third elements are `-1`, `1` and `-2` respectively and so on.

Comment: To this excellent answer I only have to add for clarification that `A.'(1)` will only work in octave, not in matlab (2015b at least).

Comment: @Leander This behavior is same in all MATLAB versions. Previously I didn't mention it since the OP is using Octave. Bur now added for completeness. Anyway thanks for pointing out

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarifications ! I couldn't use octave inherit transposing method (my teacher didnt want me too...) so I had to write a program to do the transpose by hand :https://pastebin.com/JuXkAH9b